# Chrome Content Script to Modify HTML Element

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I would like to use a Google Chrome content script to modify the following HTML code.

```
<font style="color:white;"> Text Here </font>
```

Could someone advise of the code I should use to identify the element and then change it, for example to:

```
<font style="background-color:black;color:white;"> Text Here </font>
```

Thanks for your input in advance.

Comment: you want to do this in a event, like the click of a button? Or just load the page with these settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by including the JQuery library in your extension and then you can make this change with one line of code.

```
$("font[style='color:white;']").css("background-color","black");
```

This will identify all font elements with the style `color:white;` and append `background-color:black;`.

[You can see it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/boggey79/kXQv9/)

**Here's how to include JQuery in your extension:**

Just remember to include the jquery.js file in your extension root.

```
{
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.whateveryoulike.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```